# Solving an imhogeneous nonlinear ODE from the homogeneous solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following inhomogeneous nonlinear ODE:

$
y' = a y^{-\alpha} + b
$

with $\alpha \geq 0$, $a$ is a positive function, $y(0) = y_0 \geq 0$.

I started to solve the homogeneous equation:

$
y' = a y^{-\alpha}
$

whose solution is:

$
y(x) = \left[ y_0^{\alpha+1} + (\alpha+1) \displaystyle\int_0^x a(x) dx \right]^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}
$

But I have no idea how to take into account the $b$ term:

My knowledge is very limited to linear ODEs: variation of constants method cannot work here, as the equation is nonlinear.

I also tried to rewrite the inhomogeneous equation by introducing $B$, a primitive of $b$:

$
y^\alpha (y-B)' = a
$

and make the change of variable $z := y-B$

$
(z+B)^\alpha z' = a
$

but I don't see a straightforward primitive of the left hand-side.

I am wondering to know if there is an analytical solution?
Can someone give me any tips or redirecting me to any mathematical tool I can learn to go further?

Comment: This might be helpful:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: This is not possible in the general case. Symbolic solutions may exist for special values of the constants and coefficients, especially if the coefficients are constant.

Comment: what is $b$ ?, constant or function of $x$ ?

Comment: $b$ is function of $x$. Appently, this kind of equation is called a Chini equation (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104006/inhomogeneous-bernoulli-equation, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ytnat-fracdyt), solvable only in specific cases, I'll look at it first.